# How do i write code with pcl::HarrisKeypoint2D?

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

My purpose is to extract Harris corner from Point Cloud Data(collected from the road)

```
  pcl::HarrisKeypoint2D<pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::common::IntensityFieldAccessor<pcl::PointXYZI>> harris;
  pcl::PointIndicesConstPtr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);

  harris.setInputCloud(cloud1);
  harris.setWindowHeight(3);
  harris.setWindowWidth(3);
  harris.setMinimalDistance(5);
  harris.setThreshold(0.0);
  inliers = harris.getKeypointsIndices();
  std::cout << inliers->indices.size() << std::endl;
```

This is the code i wrote, and it doesn't run. Below is the error msg in terminal.

```
test_featureTest: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = const pcl::PointIndices; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = const pcl::PointIndices*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Somebody help me.. :(

Comment: Please show the back trace of the core dump.

Comment: You have to call the `compute` function of the `harris` object

Comment: @IBitMyBytes Could you show some example code?
`harris.compute(What should go here?)`

Comment: https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_keypoint.html#a046a7cd11598b06d2076da69a3100e4b